# SQL Server Java query working in one table and not in another

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008

I have Java code which connects to SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

I have two queries, which both work fine in MS SQL Server Management studio, but only one of them works while executed from Java code. Only difference in queries is that they use different table, and both tables are located within the same database.
I am not at all DBA, but as far as I can see, permissions for both tables are similar.

What might be wrong with the tables, and where should I look for differences?

Ok, I edit this question to include details. I have used exactly same Java code, just switching the active SQL line by commenting another one away.

My Java code snippet:

```
//String SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [ipm_data].[dbo].[table1]"; //works properly
String SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [ipm_data].[dbo].[table2]"; //does not work
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
```

And errors in command prompt with non-working query:

```
>java connectURL2
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'ipm_data.dbo.table2'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError
(SQLServerException.java:216)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQ
LServerStatement.java:792)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute
(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLS
erverStatement.java:155)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:616)
        at connectURL2.main(connectURL2.java:74)
```

Where line in connectURL2.java:74 is:
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

And once again, both queries work just fine when entered at Management Studio.

Comment: Photo or that did not happen... I mean, code, SQL, errors received.

Comment: is the code used to execute them from Java the same? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I am sensing a theme.

Comment: Any more comments to this?